# What scope do I need to add for getting user email when using google+ sign in?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin

I am trying to get a access token from the google plus api.

**I run the following piece of code:**

```
private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String accountName = params[0];
        Log.e("accountName", accountName);
        String scopes = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_ME; //

        String token = null;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GOOGLE+", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e("GOOGLE+", e.getMessage());
        }
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.d("TOKEN", "token: " + s);
    }
}
```

I check my access token in postman with a HTTP GET to
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
with header Authorization Bearer

**Result:**

```
{
id: "111111111111"
name: "my name"
given_name: "my"
family_name: "name"
link: https://plus.google.com/123456789
picture: https:....jpg
gender: "male"
}
```

How can I get the user's email? What scope do I need to use?

Comment: isn't the e-mail, the `accountName` ? So you already have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth:

> The `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` scope is not recommended as a login scope because, for users who have not upgraded to Google+, it does not return the user's name or email address.

Instead, it is suggested you either use the `profile` scope or the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope (which is available as `Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN`).

**Additionally** you will need the `email` scope (this is the full name of the scope, it is not in URL format) so the email address will be returned as part of the call.

Your scopes definition might look something like:

```
String scopes = "oauth2:email " + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;
```

or

```
String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";
```

The https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo endpoint has been deprecated, works sporadically, and is scheduled to be removed in September.

Instead, you should use https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me (the "me" represents the userid for the authenticated user) and provide the Authorization header with the same Bearer token you were before.

For more information about the deprecation and migration, see https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration

Comment: Thanks, how do i add the email scope? it says there that userinfo.email is deprecated and you need to use email scope. so what do i write for that scope?

Answer (score 3):

Scope for email is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

Which needs `com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN` too.

---

So you can replace your scope as

```
private static final String SCOPE = "oauth2:"
        + TextUtils.join(" ", new String[] { Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN,
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                Scopes.PLUS_ME });
```

---

And you can use

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

which scope to being used to read user information (i.e. name, first/ lastname, profile-image, gender etc.)

Comment: how do i add both of them?

Comment: @ilan Updated the answer. Plz check

Comment: when i use your answer i get a token but when i call the HTTP GET for checking it i get:

    {
-error: {
-errors: [
-{
domain: "global"
reason: "authError"
message: "Invalid Credentials"
locationType: "header"
location: "Authorization"
}
]
code: 401
message: "Invalid Credentials"
}
}

Comment: do i need a different HTTP request for getting the info?

Comment: i get UserRecoverableAuthException, that makes a infinite  loop of google plus sign in pages.

Comment: i use 
   'String SCOPE = "oauth2:"
           + TextUtils.join(" ", new String[] { Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN,
                   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" });'

Comment: It needs to add your application package at google developer page. Did you create?

Comment: yes, if you don't create a project you get a Toast "internal error accrued"

and i wouldn't of received the info i do get (name, lastn ame ,...)

Comment: @ilan Ok undo the changes. And use only `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",            Scopes.PLUS_ME`. Without login. Actually I am not experienced into this. Used into a demo app as I added into answer and that is working for me.

Comment: i am still getting this UserRecoverableAuthException

Comment: @ilan ok. Found a solution. read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383965/userrecoverableauthexception-needpermission

Comment: you can see in my question that i am doing exactly that. i am catching the exception and calling onActivityResult

Comment: Note that the "/auth/userinfo.email" scope is deprecated and aliased to "email". Also note that the "userinfo" endpionts are also deprecated and scheduled to be removed in September 2014.

Comment: @Prisoner Hey thank you for the update. This would be better if you can add related link here.

Comment: See my answer for more info and references.