# Does official google plus integration have bugs?

Tags: android, google-plus-signin

I followed the tutorial here:
[google-plus-integration](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_add_google_sign-in)

I have tried before a simple google sign-in api without problems.
Reading the tutorial I wrote this code:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                  this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
.addApi(Plus.API)
.addScope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)
.addScope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)
.build();
```

Maybe I am stupid but this code gives me an error before compiling as:

> addScoper(com.google.android.gms.commin.api.Scope) in Builder cannot be applided to String

I tried with `new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)` but when I run the app it crashes.
Did Google really put up a broken code on their tutorial?

Comment: is your activity refering the correct layout via setContentView() ?

Comment: Where are you putting this code ? pls post the whole class

Comment: :) I put in onCreate() on ad Activity.

Comment: please post it....

Comment: @user3528466 check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25427122/2686502

Comment: Please read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892546/how-can-i-get-profile-like-gender-from-google-signin-in-android/33906880#33906880, pay attention to `.requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))`, then `.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(Plus.API)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN` instead (it returns Scope object)

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                  this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
.addApi(Plus.API)
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
.build();
```

Refer this: [Plus | Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Plus#nested-class-summary)