# Get permission on Google account settings - account permission

Tags: android, gmail-api

I developed an Android application that uses GoogleAccountCredential to authenticate with Google and uses the Gmail API. For me, it works fine. I followed all the steps to create the application in an application console.

I installed the application on another phone of my friend and this doesn't work.

I checked my friend's Google account settings - account permission (https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) and the application doesn't show up there.

The question is: why the application doesn't show up there? What do I have to do to get my application work?

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to catch the stacktrace and post it. Or see whether you can do anything with that stacktrace!

Comment: Something wrong about your OAuth? https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: Thanks for the clue Kevin. Tomorow i will try.

Comment: I catch the stacktrace and I receive: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:284)
 at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)

Comment: Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission
  at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255)
  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:279)

Answer (score 1):

The reason my app doesn't work is because I'm not catch the UserRecoverableException to triggering the intent to get the user authorize for app.
For more details take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383965/userrecoverableauthexception-needpermission)

Now I can see the permision in Google account settings - account permission.