# Google Plus login UserRecoverableAuthException in android

Tags: android, google-signin

when run's Google Login Async Class, token value null, means fetchToken returns null value. problem in fetchToken() in scope url. Under Shows **Async class code**, **Error in logcat** & **Manifest Permissions**:-

```
  public class GetUsernameTask extends AsyncTask {
            Activity mActivity;
            String mScope;
            String mEmail;


            GetUsernameTask(Activity activity, String name, String scope) {
                this.mActivity = activity;
                this.mScope = scope;
                this.mEmail = name;
            }

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                try {
                    String token = fetchToken();
                    if (token != null) {
                        // Insert the good stuff here.
                        // Use the token to access the user's Google data.
                        //...
                        Log.d(LoginActivity.class.getName(), "doInBackground token -> " + token);
                        googleToken = token;
                    //   showLoadingDialog(getString(R.string.login), getString(R.string.please_wait));
                        loginWithGoogle();

                    }else {
                        Log.d(LoginActivity.class.getName(), "doInBackground token null -> " );
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("------inCatch");
                    // The fetchToken() method handles Google-specific exceptions,
                    // so this indicates something went wrong at a higher level.
                    // TIP: Check for network connectivity before starting the AsyncTask.
                    //...
                }
                return null;
            }

            /**
             * Gets an authentication token from Google and handles any
             * GoogleAuthException that may occur.
             */
            protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
                try {

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_ACTIONS,
                            "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity");

                    String scope="oauth2:server:client_id:629234825029-1cs4vursdfs06q2ir92anucn4r04c9jfc.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";

                    System.out.println("mActivity------"+mActivity);
                    System.out.println("mEmail----"+mEmail);

                        return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, scope);






                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
                    userRecoverableException.printStackTrace();
                    // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present
                    // so we need to show the user some UI in the activity to recover.
                    Log.d(LoginActivity.class.getName(), "error in fetch" );
                    //mActivity.handleException(userRecoverableException);


                }

                catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
                    fatalException.printStackTrace();
                    // Some other type of unrecoverable exception has occurred.
                    // Report and log the error as appropriate for your app.
                    // ...
                    Log.d(LoginActivity.class.getName(), "error in fetch 2" );
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("----" + e);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

**Error in logcat:-**

```
 09-17 14:25:13.206    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission
    09-17 14:25:13.206    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
    09-17 14:25:13.206    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
09-17 14:25:13.206    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ at com.gns.socialtongits.android.LoginOptionsActivity$GetUsernameTask.fetchToken(LoginOptionsActivity.java:717)
09-17 14:25:13.206    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ at com.gns.socialtongits.android.LoginOptionsActivity$GetUsernameTask.doInBackground(LoginOptionsActivity.java:664)
09-17 14:25:13.206    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-17 14:25:13.206    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-17 14:25:13.213    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-17 14:25:13.213    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-17 14:25:13.213    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-17 14:25:13.213    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-17 14:25:13.213    8994-9095/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android I/Socket﹕ To Write: CN=3&CSID=1442480098448
09-17 14:25:13.213    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android D/com.gns.socialtongits.android.LoginActivity﹕ error in fetch
09-17 14:25:13.213    8994-9152/com.gns.socialtongits.pro.android D/com.gns.socialtongits.android.LoginActivity﹕ doInBackground token null ->
```

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: i think you have not enabled api from developer console

Comment: No, I have already enabled api in developer console. Any other idea..?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

```
catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
   startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
}
```

REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION can be any number you want - it's just used to identify this request in onActivityResult...

check out this answer over here: [UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383965/userrecoverableauthexception-needpermission)

Comment: Thanks For reply,  and i have used this code. But error in REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION. cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION can be any code you want ;) this is used so that you can identify this request when onActivityResult is called. You can set it for example to be 6666.

Comment: {"response":"1","code":7,"error_description":"google invalid token"}